# How to show highlight error in md-input-container when click submit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have updated material then I update my code like that

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input name="lastName" ng-model="lastName" required>
    <div ng-messages="userForm.lastName.$error" ng-show="userForm.lastName.$dirty">
      <div ng-message="required">This is required!</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```

It will highlight on the input when I dirty the field; however, I want to click on submit button and show highlight on the input even I don't dirty that required field.

Here is my plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/oAWaFr8OtBusRli4v8MS?p=preview
I want to click on Save button and then show error highlight on the input field.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `type="submit"` to bind your save button with form that means you are going to submit your form.

From your plunkr

```
<form name="userForm" novalidate>
  <md-input-container>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input name="lastName" ng-model="lastName" required>
    <div ng-messages="userForm.lastName.$error " ng-show="userForm.lastName.$dirty || userForm.$submitted" >
      <div ng-message='required'>This is required!</div>
    </div>
  </md-input-container>

  // added type="submit"
  <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised md-primary">Save</md-button>
</form>
```

to fire angular function on save button add `ng-submit` to your form

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="save()" novalidate>
```

Updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/F2nC9gfafGKdsm772E1i?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Update your html as below

```
<form name="userForm" novalidate>
  <md-input-container>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input name="lastName" ng-model="lastName" required>
    <div ng-messages="userForm.lastName.$error " ng-show="userForm.lastName.$touched || submitted" >
      <div ng-message='required'>This is required!</div>
    </div>
  </md-input-container>

  <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="validate()">Save</md-button>
</form>
```

Add a custom validation function inside your Controller

```
  $scope.submitted = false; //use this variable to check for validation

  //call this function instead of your action on form submit.
  $scope.validate = function(){
    if(!$scope.user.firstName.length){
      $scope.submitted = true;
      //your action here
    }
    else{
      $scope.submitted = true;
    }
  }
```

PLUNK [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/0bA8CRW6MdF6qQIpvl0v?p=preview)